# Is there any good idea to measure a time of user waited in queue? (Python)

Tags: python, time, measure

I'm making a matchmaking system using Python, and **I need to measure the times user waited in a queue.**

**Is there any better idea to optimize counting time?**

I wrote a code like this using Thread. This is a part of my code.

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Matchmaking:
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = Queue()
        self.timer = Thread(target=self._update_pending_time)
        self.timer.start()
        self.timer.join

    def _update_pending_time(self):
        sleep(1)
        # get_user_in_queue() returns DataFrame
        if not self._queue.get_user_in_queue().empty:
            self.waited_times = self._queue.get_user_in_queue().loc[:, "pending_time"] + 1
```

Comment: Just save the "start time" and compare it to the current time as needed…!?

Comment: I would include it as an attribute in the User class rather than in the Matchmaking one. When a User gets added to the queue, you can record the time stamp, then sort the users by that, for example.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding timestamp and then sorted by timestamp. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deceze commented, just save the timestamp when user enter into the queue.

Take into account that if you push users in the queue as soon as they arrive, they will be sorted by time in the queue. In this case, you can use a FIFO queue to extract always de user who arrives earlier.

However, if you want to build a matchmaking system with some intelligence taking into account something else than time on queue (level of the user, geografical zone...), take into account you shouldn't use a queue but something more complex.

Comment: I didn't mean the queue which is a data structure, I think explained in the wrong way.
Anyway, many thanks!